# How do I call this function in CodeIgniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube, youtube-api

I've got this code, but I'm not sure I make it work:

```
/**
 * Function: youtube data grabber
 *
 * @description :
 * @param  $ : video code, url type (embed/url)
 * @return : data array
 * @author : Mamun.
 * @last -modified-by: Mamun.
 */

if (! function_exists('youtube_data_grabber'))
        {

                function youtube_data_grabber($video_code, $link_type = "embed")
                {
                        if ($video_code != '')
                        {
                            if ($link_type == "embed")
                            {
                                $splited_data = explode("=",$video_code);
                                $video_unique_code = substr(strrchr($splited_data[4],"/"),1,-strlen(strrchr($splited_data[4],"&")));

                            }
                            else if ($link_type == "url")
                            {
                                $splited_data = explode("=",$video_code);
                                $video_unique_code = substr($splited_data[1],0,-strlen(strrchr($splited_data[1],"&")));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return;
                            }

                                // set feed URL
                                $feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$video_unique_code;

                                // read feed into SimpleXML object
                                $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

                            return $sxml;
                        }

                }
        } // End Youtube Function
```

I'm not sure how to activate it is what I'm trying to say. I placed it in the controller and it's within a function for one of my pages. I don't have any syntax errors. I just don't know how to wake it up and make it work. I thought I could just put `youtube_data_grabber('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAcrFym10ZI', 'url');` but that didn't work.

I got the code from [this blog](http://sumonbd.wordpress.com/2009/12/31/youtube-video-grabbing-using-zend-gdata-with-codeigniter/), and I have the zend functionality working. I tested it earlier and had no errors. I'm just having trouble with this youtube part.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your code to `application/helpers/youtube_helper.php`, then in your controller go ahead and call `$this->load->helper('youtube')`.

Only then will your `youtube_data_grabber()` function be available.

Answer (score 4):

That code should go in a helper or plugin not in the controller.  The first part of the code on that page should be in your controller.  The one you pasted is just an alternate version.